# Sentinels in non-pointer arrays

Tags: c

Let's say I have the following array:

```
int numbers[] = {-2,4,9,11};
int sum=sum_list(numbers);
```

If I were to pass pointers, I could add in a `NULL` at the end of the list to signal the size of it. However, in the above non-pointer list, is there a way to do that? If not, is the way around this just to explicitly pass the size of the array to the callee, for example:

```
int sum_list(int numbers[], size_z len);
```

Comment: NULL = 0.  What's the difference between that and 0?

Comment: @OldProgrammer the issue is `0` is also a valid value here for the list of numbers.

Comment: I'm not aware if it is possible but as you also asked for workaround so, You can set first element of array as size of array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with an array of non-pointer values such as this, you basically have two choices:

1. Pass the length of the list to any function that also receives the list
2. Designate some value that is outside the range of acceptable values to use as an end-of-list indicator

A third choice would be to implement a Pascal-type array where index 0 contains the length of the array.

Comment: what would be an example of #2?

Comment: @David542 As an example, if only non-negative numbers are valid values for the list, you could use -1 to signify the end of the list.

Comment: could be INT_MIN, especially if you are using only positive integers  @dbush yes or -1. Could be 0 if you don't have empty value in your array.

Comment: Note that the first approach is more efficient because you avoid checking the value at each iteration, you can simply use `while (len--)` in your loop which will work better with SIMD.